# Start a SlideTransition's animation from method

Tags: animation, flutter

I've been trying to make a Container move from the bottom of the screen to the middle when I click a button. However, I can't figure out how to properly execute the animation only when I press the button. Furthermore, it seems that when I call the _customWidget.startAnimation() method an error stating I called the function on void always happens. Here are my questions:

How do I access startAnimation() inside MyCustomWidget properly and how should I structure the code to only run the animation when I press the button?

Main.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'MyCustomWidget.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  MyCustomWidget _customWidget;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _customWidget = MyCustomWidget();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Center(
          child: MyCustomWidget(),
        ),
        FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () => {} //_customWidget.startAnimation() gives an error,
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

MyCustomWidget.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyCustomWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyCustomWidgetState createState() => _MyCustomWidgetState();

  startAnimation() {
    debugPrint('is this where the function should be?');
  }
}

class _MyCustomWidgetState extends State<MyCustomWidget>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _animationController;
  Animation<Offset> _offsetAnimation;

  void startAnimation() {
    debugPrint('or is it here?');
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    //Following code should go in startAnimation() rather than letting it execute
    //every time the object is created
    _animationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
    )..repeat(reverse: true);
    _offsetAnimation = Tween<Offset>(
      begin: Offset.zero,
      end: const Offset(1.5, 0.0),
    ).animate(CurvedAnimation(
      parent: _animationController,
      curve: Curves.elasticIn,
    ));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SlideTransition(
      position: _offsetAnimation,
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        height: 50,
        width: 50,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _animationController.dispose();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Flutter, you access the child widgets using `key`. You also have to make the state public (remove the underscore from `_MyCustomWidgetState`)

So in the child:

```dart
class MyCustomWidget extends StatelessWidget {
     final Key key;
     MyCustomWidget(this.key) : super(key: key);
     [...]
```

in the parent:

```dart
GlobalKey<MyCustomWidgetState> key = GlobalKey<MyCustomWidgetState>();
[...]
Center(
     child: MyCustomWidget(key)
)
```

and calling the child (from parent):

```dart
key.currentState.startAnimation();
```

Answer (score 1):

Tien's answer got my widget working correctly, here's how the two files look after the modifications:

Main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'MyCustomWidget.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  GlobalKey<MyCustomWidgetState> _customWidgetKey =
      GlobalKey<MyCustomWidgetState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Center(
          child: MyCustomWidget(_customWidgetKey),
        ),
        FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () => _customWidgetKey.currentState.show(),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

MyCustomWidget.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyCustomWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final Key key;
  MyCustomWidget(this.key) : super(key: key);

  @override
  MyCustomWidgetState createState() => MyCustomWidgetState();
}

class MyCustomWidgetState extends State<MyCustomWidget>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _animationController;
  Animation<Offset> _offsetAnimation;

  void show() {
    setState(() {
      _animationController.animateTo(1.0);
    });
  }

  void hide() {
    setState(() {
      _animationController.animateTo(0.0);
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _animationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
    );
    _offsetAnimation = Tween<Offset>(
      begin: Offset(0.0, 40),
      end: Offset.zero,
    ).animate(CurvedAnimation(
      parent: _animationController,
      curve: Curves.easeInOutQuint,
    ));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SlideTransition(
      position: _offsetAnimation,
      child: Container(
        child: FloatingActionButton(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          onPressed: () => hide(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _animationController.dispose();
  }
}
```

This gets you a button which brings up a button when pressed. Clicking the second button sends it down. This whole thing is going to be useful to make custom widgets pop up and down!